# "_clean_type_info_names_internal" taking 50% execution time

Tags: c++, std, profiler, msvcrt

I am profiling my application witch uses IT++ library.
I found that much of the time (50%) is being taken by this function:

`_clean_type_info_names_internal()`.

The function is internal to MSVCR100, and is called at `metric(j) = std::exp(-sqr(rx_symbols(l) - channel(l) * symbols(j))/ N0);`

I tried disabling RTTI, with no luck.

Is it just an error of the profiling? Is that function part of the `exp()` function?
Any help (or clue) will be much appreciated, even if it is only information about the function purpose itself.

Comment: It looks like maybe it's wrestling with run-time type casting. What do `rx_symbols` and `symbols` do?

Comment: They are just cvec classes (arrays of complex<double>). The () operator is overloaded so it access the element in that possition. The only "real" functions are the exp() and sqr().

Comment: Well, you know, my swiss-army-knife answer to any such problem is [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771).

Comment: Thank you, but if I interrupt my program using the debugger I can see only the program in that line of code, but I cannot see it inside _clean_type_info_names_internal() since it is an internal function. It is only shown on the profiler. Any way to see that function on the debugger side?

Comment: If you could see inside it, you couldn't do anything about it. What you need to know is what is the call chain going into it, from your code - i.e why is it being called. That will give you a clue of what you can do about it.